# With / While / Nothing

Tags: word-usage

here's a context

The reason I like summer more than any other season is because I can do what I couldn't do because of cold weather. For example,

> 1. I can drink outdoors with having festive feel at Hongdae.
> 2. I can drink outdoors while having festive feel at Hongdae.
> 3. I can drink outdoors having festive feel at Hongdae.

I was about to use #1, but I've come to wonder which option is the best. If possible, can I ask difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these is very idiomatic in Anglo-American dialects.

- We're unlikely to say that we "have a festive feel". In the first place, we don't ordinarily say that people *HAVE an ADJ feel*. That is an idiom used of events and occasions, and it expresses their mood or tone: *The concert had a festive feel*.

  (Note that we also don't say that we "HAVE an ADJ feel**ing**". That idiom expresses a suspicion or expectation: *I have a bad feeling about this project* means that I suspect it will turn out badly.)

  With people we use *feel* as a verb: *I feel festive*.
- We're also unlikely to use *while ... VERBing* in this sort of context.  *While ... VERBing* clauses are characteristic of written rather than spoken English anyway, and they tend to suggest that the connection between the main-clause and *while*-clause activities is unexpected: *He can drink a glass of beer while standing on his head.*

  A *when* clause is more likely here: *I can drink outside when I feel festive*.
- Finally, *festive* itself is not a term we ordinarily apply to individuals. It's an adjective form of *feast* or *fest*, so it's most often used to describe events or groups of people at an event. We don't really have a common adjective for the sort of pleasurable emotion you seem to have in mind; we have to approach it periphrastically.

  > *I can drink outside when I'm having a good time*.

ADDED:
I see you've added the phrase *at Hongdae* to your examples. Hongdae appears to be the entertainment/nightlife district in Seoul, so using that (or a local equivalent, like Laclede's Landing or the Delmar Loop in St Louis) would probably convey the appropriate emotion all by itself.

> *I can drink outside when I go down to the Landing*.